# Why does get getElementsByClassName() return undefined, when using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript, puppeteer

Right now I'm trying to get some elements using puppeteer, to get some class items(divs). I know getElementsByClassName returns a list, which you have to parse through. However for me the function just says undefined, even when I try it in the browser (Latest version of chrome).

Heres the code (typescript btw):

```
private async getElementsFromBrowser(url : string) : Promise<any[]>{
  const page : Page = await goToPage(url)
  const result = await page.evaluate( arr => {
    //this is where the error comes in
    let setOfElements = document.getElementsByClassName('classnamethatexists');

    arr = setOfElements;
    return arr;
  }
  return Promise.resolve(result);
}
```

and the html:

```
<div class='classnamethatexists'>"This is an example of the text I want to get"</div>
<div class='classnamethatexists'>"This is an example of the text I want to get"</div>
<div class='classnamethatexists'>"This is an example of the text I want to get"</div>
<div class='classnamethatexists'>"This is an example of the text I want to get"</div>
```

is there a way for the function to not return undefined;

Comment: question one would be "when does this code run"? Did you remember to either mark it as `defer` so that it runs after the DOM has been finalised, or lacking that, making it run _after_ DOMContentLoaded is signaled?

Comment: The code runs in a function where the promise is put into an array of type any. So like `arrayOfElements = await getElementsFromBrowser. And no I'm not using defer, should I?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple things wrong with your code.

**page.evaluate cannot return a HTMLCollection**

[`page.evaluate`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) can only return serializable data, that is data which can be send from the browser context to the Node.js context via `JSON.stringify`. [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a HTMLCollection, which cannot be serialized.

**Use `page.$` or `page.$$` to return element handles**

To query elements with a specific class, you better use [`page.$$`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) function in combination with the [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors). This will return a [element handle](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) which can be used for further execution inside the Node.js execution context.

**async return value**

As you already declared the function as `async` any result will implicitly become the result of a Promise. Therefore, you do not need to use `Promise.resolve` when returning the value.

---

**Resulting code**

Putting it all together, the resulting code looks like this:

```js
private async getElementsFromBrowser(url : string) : Promise<any[]>{
  const page = await goToPage(url); // I imagine this calls page.goto and returns the page
  const elements = await page.$$('.classnamethatexists');
  return elements;
}
```

Comment: Hey, so I know I said it worked, but if i have multiple objects how would I parse through them with the page.$$? In the information there is nothing about there being some other objects there.

Comment: It's an array of element handles. You can loop over them: `for (const el of elements) { await el... }`